# Python: JSON saved as string, can't get it back to JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I had some JSON data that I converted to string using:

```
myString = str(myJSON)
```

and I saved into an SQLite database. Now, when I retrieve `myString` looks more or less like this:

```
'{u\'foo\': False, u\'bar\': 20, u\'name\': u\'Anna\'}'
```

I am having trouble making it go back to JSON. I think the main issue is these extra `u\` and `\` that appeared.

I have tried using `json.dumps` and/or `json.loads` with no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting errors form python?  If so, what are those errors?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get a dictionary back.

```
import ast

original = {'foo': False, 'bar': 20, 'name': 'Anna'}
dict_string = str(original)
print original == dict_string  # False
print original == ast.literal_eval(dict_string)  # True
```

That said, you should be using something like `json.dumps` and `json.loads` in the future to store and retrieve dictionaries if they need to be stored stringified. It's generally not a good thing to cast dictionaries directly into strings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have JSON. You have a Python dictionary.

If you did have JSON, you wouldn't need to convert it to a string, because it would already be one. However, as the db value shows, what you have actually done is convert a dict straight to a string.

Don't do any of this. If you are actually receiving JSON somewhere, then you shouldn't be parsing it to a dict before writing it to the database. If you're creating this dict programatically, then you should convert it to a string via `json.dumps(my_data)` before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Karin said, your string is not JSON, that said, you should use [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dump) directly with the var `myJSON` (this var **should** be a `dict`) like this:

```
    myJSON = {'foo': False,
              'bar': 20,
              'name': 'Anna'}

    with open('foo.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(myJSON, f)
```

Now, to get rid of the  `\` character in your string, just use [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

eg:

```
 import ast

 json_dict = ast.literal_eval(myString.replace('\\', ''))
```